# increase and decrease the font size of the text on zoom in out slider using jquery cycle2

Tags: jquery, zooming

I used the jquery cycle cycle2 plugin.I want to Increase and decrease the font size of the text content whenever the slides get zoom in and zoom out respectively. The Images were used get worked nicely.

There is an option for animIn and animOut but am not sure about how to make use of the manipulating font size. I need to reduce and increase the font size when the division get shrinked and enlarged automatically. Because to change font size on screen resize or any click action is possible and I had it. But manipulating font size on automatic zoom in and out needs to work.

If anyone help this great appreciation for you.....

Comment: from jquery .animate doc's " Or, if you want to animate font size, you would use fontSize or the CSS equivalent 'font-size' rather than simply 'font'."

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourClass').animate({ fontSize : '11pt' });
```

then make font bigger:

```
$('.yourClass').animate({ fontSize : '18pt' });
```

css equivalent works too :

```
 $('.yourClass').animate({ 'font-size' : '11pt' });
```